# What should be the standard timeout timing in case modal does not open up for google pay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-pay

What should be the standard timeout timing in case modal does not open up for google pay

Comment: What is "*standard timeout timing*"?

Comment: @InSync I have one scenario that when a user click on Google pay button and model popup is not open. I have to show error message in UI, for that is there any standard time to open model popup or how to find out error scenario?